# How to save <class "ctypes.c_char_Array> with pickle

Tags: python, pickle, ctypes

I'm doing research on palmprint recognition. for that I use the edcc library for the introduction of the palmprint. but i have problem in saving the encoding result from palm. I want to save the encoding result into a file, but I get an error like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Coba/PalmDetection/PalmRecognition.py", line 18, in <module>
    pickle.dump(one_palmprint_code, config_dictionary_file)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_849'>: attribute lookup c_char_Array_849 on ctypes failed
```

My code like this :

```
import os
import edcc
import cv2
import pickle

TEST_PALMPRINT_DATA_DIR = "/home/pi/Coba/PalmDetection/Data"
TEST_A_01_PALMPRINT_IMAGE = os.path.join(TEST_PALMPRINT_DATA_DIR, "Palm1.jpeg")
#TEST_A_02_PALMPRINT_IMAGE = os.path.join(TEST_PALMPRINT_DATA_DIR, "a_02.bmp")
TEST_B_01_PALMPRINT_IMAGE = os.path.join(TEST_PALMPRINT_DATA_DIR, "palme.jpeg")
#TEST_B_02_PALMPRINT_IMAGE = os.path.join(TEST_PALMPRINT_DATA_DIR, "b_02.bmp")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = edcc.EncoderConfig(29, 5, 5, 10)
    encoder = edcc.create_encoder(config)
    one_palmprint_code = encoder.encode_using_file(TEST_A_01_PALMPRINT_IMAGE)
    with open('encode.encode', 'wb') as config_dictionary_file:
      pickle.dump(one_palmprint_code, config_dictionary_file)
    another_palmprint_code = encoder.encode_using_file(TEST_B_01_PALMPRINT_IMAGE)
    similarity_score = one_palmprint_code.compare_to(another_palmprint_code)
    print(
        "{} <-> {} similarity score:{}".format(
            TEST_A_01_PALMPRINT_IMAGE, TEST_B_01_PALMPRINT_IMAGE, similarity_score
        )
    )
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The `edcc` module must use `ctypes` internally, but really should hide that fact instead of returning a ctypes-wrapped object.  A `ctypes.c_char_Array_849` is just a C-compatible wrapper around an array of bytes.  You can access the equivalent Python `bytes` object via the `.raw` property (what `edcc` should return instead) and write that to the file:

```py
import ctypes
import pickle

one_palmprint_code = (ctypes.c_char * 849)()

with open('encode.encode', 'wb') as config_dictionary_file:
    #pickle.dump(one_palmprint_code, config_dictionary_file) # reproduces error
    config_dictionary_file.write(one_palmprint_code.raw)
```